# How do you access the changed and unchanged attributes in a RemoteExecutionContext?

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azureservicebus, dynamics-crm-online

How do you access the changed and unchanged attributes in a RemoteExecutionContext?

I've successfully got the SDK example sandbox plugin sending on Create to an Azure Service Bus queue.

Next I wanted to handle the Update message, however I can't seem to get at all the attributes.

Reading what I can find, it mentioned the Pre- and PostImage and I can see some of the attributes ...

```
// context is the passed in RemoteExecutionContext
var postEntityImage = context.PostEntityImages["AsynchronousStepPrimaryName"];
foreach (var attribute in postEntityImage.Attributes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", attribute.Key, attribute.Value);
}

var inputParametersEntity = (Entity) context.InputParameters["Target"];
foreach (var attribute in inputParametersEntity.Attributes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", attribute.Key, attribute.Value);
}
```

but how can I obtain the remaining attributes?

To further confuse me, I've sent a second message where I amended other attributes, but these don't appear in either set of attributes

Comment: Could the missing attributes simply have `null` values in the database?

Comment: Nope, they all have strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target in a plugin will only contain the values to be updated.  If you want to ensure that an attribute will always be there, you need to add it as an entity image.  A pre-entity will contain the values before the transaction has occurred, the post entity will contain the values after the update had occurred.

Right click on the step in the Plugin registration tool, and select "Add image"

Comment: ah, I didn't pick up that I have to explicitly add the pre or post image. I'd assumed CRM did this as part of the process of sending the RemoteExecutionContext too the Service Bus queue

Comment: Nope.  It requires a database lookup, so it is only performed when you say you need it.

Comment: Can you give an example or reference to how to?

Comment: Right click on the step in the Plugin registration tool,  and select add image

Comment: @SteveC, if this answered it for you, please mark it as such, so it doesn't show up as unanswered.